# different excerpt in php

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi how to excerpt this code using php ?

> It's the wordpress content .
>   but there is not this way in wordpress

**From**

```
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
.
.
.
```

**To**

```
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
```

Comment: What you're asking about is not really clear. How this divs are generated? Where do they come from? And as rnevius pointed out, your HTML is invalid - you're missing the closing `>` for all your `</div>` tags.

Comment: oh no ! it's a error in my type in stackoverflow !

Comment: the html is in a variable?

Comment: yes, it's a field in wordpress metabox

Answer (score 2):

you can try this using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
//if html is retrieved in a variable like $html, then
$html = "<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>
<div class='first'>first</div>
<div class='second'>second</div>";


$validate = array('first'=>true,'second'=>true);
$response = trim(preg_replace_callback('/<div\s?.*\/div>/',function($match)use(&$validate){
    reset($validate);$key = key($validate);
    if(strstr($match[0],$key) != false && $validate[$key] == true){
        $validate[$key] = false;
        return $match[0];
    }
    next($validate);$key = key($validate);
    if(strstr($match[0],$key) != false && $validate[$key] == true){
        $validate[$key] = false;
        return $match[0];
    }
},$html));
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I don't think this regex should work, if you want to match all the div's content you can use `/<div\s?.*?>(.*?)<\/div>/`. See https://regex101.com/r/cX4kS8/1

Comment: @vard have you executed the php?

Comment: @vard preg_replace_callback  get a  loop of matches from pattern.

Comment: Just did, it indeed work. My bad, I got confused by the fact that the regex seemed to match the class name + the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the div after the second one with the following css:

```
div.first, div.second {
    display: none;
}
div.first:first-child,
div.second:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

To remove completely the divs from the markup in PHP you should need regex, but [parsing HTML in a regex can lead to terrible results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3305116).

If you really need to go in that way, you should better consider to store your div's content in different fields.